# How to check if sphinx matched all the words?

Tags: search, sphinx, full-text-search

In Sphinx QL, I have queries of form :

```
SELECT id FROM index WHERE MATCH('word1|word2|word3') OPTION ranker=matchany, max_matches=100;
```

Is there a native way to check if all the words where successfully matched with at least one document? Note that it might not have to be a single document. For instance, `word1` can match `document1` , `word2` can match `document2` and `word3` can match `document3`. The result is a success here. Assume there was no match for `word3`, the result is a failure then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running SHOW META right after the query - Will give you per keyword hit count

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.1/sphinxql-show-meta.html

Comment: Thanks Barry ! That should suffice my usecase :)

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that all words got matched at same document you have to issue 2nd query
SELECT id FROM index WHERE MATCH('word1 word2 word3');

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my condition is that the words are not in the same document.